# Dynamic form in ASP.NET and SQL Server

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

Some context: I currently have a form that works as a filter for a document searcher, there's a drop down list that is loaded with data from a SQL Server table, and when I change it the fields change their display, depending on the type of document.

How it works is that I have all the fields on html, and with the class I determine which field corresponds to which document type. So every time I add a new document type I have to edit the html to include the new type to the fields.

My question is: how can I make it so that I don't need to change the html or js or any code in the web app and only change the SQL Server every time I have to add a new type of document?

Comment: This is a very broad question and without code makes it more difficult, but I have forms that are completely based off database data.  The entire form, all fields of every type are loaded from a DB.  So you would just have to use your back end code to dynamically add the fields using C#, if you need types based off each value in your drop down, then you would loop through your SQL data and add whatever needed for each value in the loop

Comment: @Brad, I made it broad because I need to redo the whole thing. I'm looking for suggestions to change the web code once.

Answer (score 0):

To implement extendable document you can try the following:
add new table:

```
document_type_fields:
id, document_type, field_name, field_type
1, sms, received_date, date
2, sms, content, text(255)
3, email, content, textarea(1000000)
4, email, to_address, text(255)
```

In order to render document fields, find its type, find document type fields:
sms:

```
received_date, date
content, text(255)
```

add javascript switch (document_type) and display its fields as html controls

keep document_type-specific fields in separate table:

```
document_specific_fields(document_id, field_name, field_value)
```

document_id is primary key and foreign key referencing main table (with fields common to all document types):

```
documents(document_id, document_type, ...)
```